# How to use Eloquent to traverse relationships outside Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using eloquent ORM outside Laravel. I do simple CRUD operations on tables and views but I cannot work out how to traverse or set up relationships. I tried this code

```
<?php

include 'eloquent_database.php';
class User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'user';
        protected $primaryKey = 'userId';

       public function company() {
           return $this->belongsTo('company', 'companyID');
       }
}  
// Create the company model
class Company extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'company';
    protected $primaryKey = 'companyID';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('user', 'userId');
    }
}


// Grab all from company table
$companys = Company::all(); 


foreach ($companys as $company) {
        echo "<B>" .$company->name . "<br>";
        $users = $company->users();
        foreach($users as $user) {

            echo $user->userName . "<br>";
        }
};
?>
```

but i do not get back any users for a company. Just the company name

thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Cryode said already:

```
$company->users(); // relation object
$company->users; // collection of related users
```

so you need the latter.

However, your relation is wrong, so it will not work anyway, until you fix it like below:

```
// Company model
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('user', 'companyId');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the relationship incorrectly. If you want to return the *result* of a relationship (i.e., the actual model[s]), you call the property, not the method.

```
// Will perform a query and return the results of the relationship.
$users = $company->users;

// Will return the relationship object you defined in your method. It's normal PHP, zero magic.
$usersRelationshipObject = $company->users();
```

[Read the documentation more thoroughly.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)